# String replacing in large project

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I have a big web project with a lot of static html files. Is there a way to manipulate these files with node.js? I mean that if I want to change tabindex on 50 files can I do some selection like

```
$('input.myClass').attr('tabindex', '-1');
```

and apply it on all? Can I manipulate my project's files this way? Modifying, replacing strings depending on some criteria?

The only alternative I have for automating large changes is bash(for now) but I don't think it's a good idea to spend that much time to build custom scripts for css selectors.

Comment: You can use `cheerio` (or similar module) to load an HTML file, augment it, then save it back.

Comment: I have to say that I never used Node.js before. So, are you saying that I actually can do that with node.js+cheerio? It should be internal to the node.js project directories I suppose or it is also possible to do it system wide?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Basically, it's a task to be completed once, so there's no need to keep it as a part of your project. It's a good practice, however, to store these tasks (even one-timers) somewhere.

Comment: I meant that I store my project's files, let's say, in /home/me/projects. I have to move them to, let's say, /var/www/nodejs-project-files or can I do it outside and node js could be configured to work outside default directories? I want to keep files as separate as possible and not to move them back an forth any time that I have to do some manipulation.

Comment: Of course node can work with those (if it's permitted to read/write them), you can just set up a `processDir` argument and change that accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple script using cheerio that demonstrates how to manipulate html files.  assuming the html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Test Page</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <ul id="fruits">
            <li class="apple">Apples</li>
            <li class="orange">Orange</li>
            <li class="pear">Pear</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The script to add tabindex would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node 
var fs = require('fs'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

fs.readFile('index.html', { encoding:'utf-8' }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var $ = cheerio.load( data );

    var apple = $('.apple');

    apple.attr('tabindex', '-1');

    // now write the file out
    console.log( $.html() );
});
```

The modified html now looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="fruits">
    <li class="apple" tabindex="-1">Apples</li>
    <li class="orange">Orange</li>
    <li class="pear">Pear</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```